# Asp.net Google Maps Markers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, maps, markers, pins

I have a list of objects that have title, latitude, longitude and description and want to place them in google map but I can't place the pins in the map. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance! :)

```
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                markers += "{";
                markers += string.Format("'title':'{0}',", item.Name);
                markers += string.Format("'lat':'{0}',", item.Latitude);
                markers += string.Format("'lng':'{0}',", item.Longitude);
                markers += string.Format("'description':'{0}',", item.Description);
                markers += "},";
            }

            markers += "];";
            ViewBag.Markers = markers;
            return View();
```

And the .cshtml code

```
    function InitializeMap() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(24.4324, 26.83333);

        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var markers = @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Markers);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatLng = { data.lat, data.lng };
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                Title: data.title
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: The map is loaded? Is there some error in the browser console?

Comment: The map is only loaded when I remove the for loop from cshtml, so my guess is that something is wrong with the Viewbag format I pass to view

Comment: After pass the view bag write console.log(markers); and see at the console browser what happens (ie: f12 Chrome)

Comment: After I removed the loop: http://prntscr.com/qmgfjn and with the code I provided http://prntscr.com/qmgfz4

Comment: please add your data to so we can trace your problem @mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the problem was that for some reason the coordinates were with a comma and not a dot ( ex initial coord was 21.32754 and in javascript were 21,32754) so the only thing I had to do is convert it to float. Thank you guys!